# Create a jenkins job programmatically using C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins

Is there a way to create a `jenkins` job using C# code?

- I have the config file.
- I have the `createItem` URL.

How to use these to create a `jenkins` job?

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Do you have any error messages? Please show the code that you have written so far.

Comment: I had created a request object of HttpWebRequest of the URL(htttp://testjenkins.com/createItem?name=FIRSTJOB) and set the Method to "POST" and ContentType to "application/xml". I am getting a bad request error. I have also written all the config.xml bytes to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the source to add jenkins job using C#:
uri : is JENKINS URL (http://testjenkins.com/createItem?name=J1)
J1: is the job name
filename: is the full path of the config.xml for the job

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "password");
        byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
        string base64Credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
        string ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        string postData = ret;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        string result = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the job configuration xml file you can use the [CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI):

http://Jenkins_Master:port/cli/command/create-job

Make sure you have all relevant plugins that are defined in the job you created.